# Why does Visual Studio gray out parameter names?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, parameters

Does anyone know why VS likes to gray out parameter names in a function?  Is it to discourage reads/writes to the parameter stack allocation?  Or perhaps to make aware of the fact that you are using the parameter and not, say, a class member variable?  Just curious.

Comment: No offense, but I feel this would be a better fit for [the MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home).  You're more likely to get actual answers there than you are here, due to this being a stylistic decision by someone at Microsoft.

Comment: It is just a theme selection, the default theme doesn't pick anything garish and gray here doesn't mean "disabled".  Just "different".  You can make it anything you want with Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Display Items = "C++ Parameters".

Comment: @HansPassant that's more or less what I was looking for, thanks.  If you'll just make an answer out of that I'll accept it.

Comment: Just tell us what you end up doing and mark the post as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm @HansPassant's comment of being able to change C++ parameter font color in Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Display Items.  Here is the original:

[image: Gray Parameters]

After the change:

[image: Teal Parameters]

I chose teal because it didn't seem to clash with other readily present colors.

At any rate, it was not colored grey because of the parameter not being used.

Answer (score 3):

Very late to answering, but what I've found is that this isn't just a stylistic thing for C++. Grey lines, variables, and methods indicate that the preprocessor for VS doesn't believe this code will ever be executed on your machine. This is primarily due to machine configuration/ environment variables.

If parameter names are being grayed out, I would hazard to guess that the function itself is overloaded with another, more compatible method.
Example: func(u_64 A) on a 32-bit OS will be grayed out, but func(u_32 B) will not

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow!  It would be better if you provided more hard research before posting a guess.  I am familiar with the case you describe which is what prompted the question, so I was looking for definite answers as to whether or not this was the specific case with Visual Studio.  Apparently it's not - see my answer mentioning @HansPassant's comment on the question.  All the same, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addendum to Bondolin's helpful answer.  Under Display Items, choose `C++ Parameters` and set the `Item foreground`.

[image]

[image]